# Issue with changing Tableau workbook's owner using TSC

Tags: python, json, api, tableau-api

I am using Tableau Server Client to programmatically publish and change it's owner. I am using following code:

```
request_options = TSC.RequestOptions(pagesize=1000)
all_workbooks = list(TSC.Pager(server.workbooks, request_options))

for workbook in all_workbooks:
    if workbook.name == 'report-test' and workbook.project_name=='folder-Test':
        workbook.owner = 'new_owner'
        print('Trying to update the owner')
        workbook = server.workbooks.update(workbook)
        print('Owner changed successfully')`
```

I am getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tsc_refresh_schedule.py", line 124, in 
main()
File "tsc_refresh_schedule.py", line 65, in main
run(args)
File "tsc_refresh_schedule.py", line 100, in run
workbook = server.workbooks.update(workbook)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tableauserverclient/server/endpoint/endpoint.py", line 116, in wrapper
return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tableauserverclient/server/endpoint/workbooks_endpoint.py", line 84, in update
server_response = self.put_request(url, update_req)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tableauserverclient/server/endpoint/endpoint.py", line 85, in put_request
content_type=content_type)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tableauserverclient/server/endpoint/endpoint.py", line 54, in _make_request
self._check_status(server_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tableauserverclient/server/endpoint/endpoint.py", line 68, in _check_status
raise ServerResponseError.from_response(server_response.content, self.parent_srv.namespace)
tableauserverclient.server.endpoint.exceptions.ServerResponseError:

400000: Bad Request
Payload is either malformed XML/JSON or incomplete
```

Can someone please help me out?
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no property `owner` on the Workbook.  You would need to set the `owner_id` which is the `id` of the user.  See the help documentation [here](https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/api-ref#workbooks).

Another great library which obfuscates many of the underlying challenges is [Tableau Tools](https://github.com/bryantbhowell/tableau_tools).  I have used both and find this library much easier to use.

Comment: Thank you so much..I was missing the owner_id

Comment: Even though I assign owner id to the workbook, I am still getting the same exception

Comment: I would take a look at the [samples](https://github.com/tableau/server-client-python/tree/master/samples) in the Github project and try to mimic how they work.  Hard to tell what's happening without the full code.